# SQL stored function call from vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I had a stored function created in SQL Server. When I try to call that from vb.net with command text like...

```
---- Returning error
lobjCommand.CommandText="Select function_name(value1)"

----- Executing properly without errors    
lobjCommand.CommandText="Select dbo.function_name(value1)"
```

Can someone suggest what exactly the dbo playing the magic...

Thanks in advance
Rupesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dbo` is most likely your default schema. It stands for [**Database Owner**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905208%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

When running functions in your SQL queries you need to specify the schema that the function belongs to.

If you don't then there could be two different functions with the name `function_name` belong to two different schemas. Without mentioning the schema, the server won't know which function you are calling.

Comment: Thanks Curt, Is there any way we execute a scalar function  from vb.net other than using a select statement

Comment: I would recommend using a query like your second one, `Select dbo.function_name(value1)`. I see no problem using this. Alternatively you could move this query into a Stored Procedure and execute the stored procedure to get the value returned.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server engine always parse the query into pieces, if you don't use the prefix definitely it going search for object in similar name with different users before it uses [dbo]. I would suggest you follow the prefix mechanism not only to satisfy the best practices, also to avoid performance glitches and make the code scalable.

old question asked refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273411/the-dbo-prefix-in-database-object-names-can-i-ignore-it)